# WP7 TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime not giving correct results

Tags: windows-phone-7, timezone

I'm attempting to convert a time from UTC to the Phone's local time. For this I'm using the following:

```
if (progress.ActionDateTime.HasValue)
                    progress.ActionDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(progress.ActionDateTime.Value, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

However, the time remains exactly the same after the conversion has took place. Is this method working in WP7?

Comment: Try this. progress.ActionDateTime.ToLocalTime();

Comment: That does seem to work, I wonder if I'm just not using the ConvertTime function properly or whether it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DateTime does not store information about the time zone. [According to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382835.aspx), `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` will use the DateTime.Kind property to determine how the time should be converted:

- DateTimeKind.Local and DateTimeKind.Unspecified: Converts the local time to the time in destinationTimeZone.
- DateTimeKind.Utc: Converts Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) to the time in destinationTimeZone.

Since you're using `TimeZoneInfo.Local` for the second parameter (which specify the destination time zone), I'm assuming that you're DateTimeKind is either Local or Unspecified. Therefore, you're converting a local date to a local date, which obviously won't work.

`DateTime.ToLocalTime` also uses the DateTimeKind. [According to the documentation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx)

- Utc: This instance of DateTime is converted to local time.
- Local: No conversion is performed.
- Unspecified: This instance of DateTime is assumed to be a UTC time, and the conversion is performed as if Kind were Utc.

Basically, while `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` considers that DateTimeKind.Unspecified = Local, `DateTime.ToLocalTime` considers that DateTimeKind.Unspecified = Utc. It explains why the latter works while the former doesn't.